# Can you earn Free Rider multiple times?

Tags: dont-get-fired

The title is self explanatory. I don't remember exactly how I got it the first time, but I was leaving the game open and alone for at least 10 minutes, and suddenly got it. I've also heard that its a random drop from getting jobs once they turn green, which I focused on for a good 30 minutes but didn't get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. I've waited a lot to get it my first time, then, a few promotions/resignations later, I got it again by randomly leaving the game open for a few minutes - unintentionally, this time.